# Need proper syntax for using public key generated by PuTTYgen in GCE

Tags: ssh, putty, google-compute-engine, public-key, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to Google VM via PuTTY and can't seem to add the public key properly.

I have followed instructions on as per:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/console#sshkeys

However, I seem to have pasted the key incorrectly.

My PuTTY key is generated as

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20141121"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAklz2lupNnZFPXTRivb8ba4JB90YLc7qZh05d
OcFq9WqRuUNTu2f0fgC49FEEx9aCCWOrGZS/CWpoKmHd1Q4pEfHFJ/EOWB1ZOpNh
LnIT/HZT6aOLBXZg3aoyrL9BXyh3eWnUA8qOZDa/Jl4vt1alPO6XsYzfl7YUs+m7
GcUnTgvwxn+beCXuLZbDlVP/tco6UKSx4Rj0uVkwdsgstCs2b0lnx2o+vabVI+28
WHqsORahZMdSL8yXiFJ+pPye8wkolmicvfVJU0mqflhsmC0w2TJ4AGnkHOG9OjwJ
EaekMA89w7Of9W/WXE94zAj8LeYn2LMEYkKQHu+EJ902gfaLiw==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

Can anyone post the key in the correct format as per the link I have mentioned above:

```
protocol publickey username
```

I am not clear which is which in this case e.g should I include the quotes in rsa-key as well as the number 20141121 ?

I am messing up on the syntax so details would be appreciated as I am already able to SSH using Google Clouds tools and also able to connect using PuTTY but fail at authentication.

Comment: Thanks Martin so this worked in terms of pasting the ssh key. I copied the Key directly from Putty's keygen and pasted it in the 'key's section of vm instance. However, when I used Putty with the private key and tried to connect it did ask for username. As soon as I give username it says "server refused key". To ensure I am not mistaken about the username I did typed "whoami" at the command prompt as well as "id" to confirm my username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Load your key to [PuTTYgen](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey-puttygen);
- To the *Key comment* box, enter you GCE username – this should be your Google account with symbols replaced by an underscore (`_`) everything after `@` ignored. Or specify any other account name you want to be created.
- And see the box [*Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file*](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-pastekey).

For details, see (my) guide [Connecting Securely to Google Compute Engine Server with SFTP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_google_compute_engine) with WinSCP.

Example (not your key):

[image: PuTTYgen]

I.e. the format you need to paste to the `authorized_keys` file is very different to the format, you see when you open the key file in a text editor.

Also the format you have included in your message is not the PuTTY key format, it's the ssh.com format. Which is completely irrelevant to your setup (PuTTY client and OpenSSH server).

Comment: Thanks Martin so this worked in terms of pasting the ssh key. I copied the Key directly from Putty's keygen and pasted it in the 'key's section of vm instance. However, when I used Putty with the private key and tried to connect it did ask for username. As soon as I give username it says "server refused key". To ensure I am not mistaken about the username I did typed "whoami" at the command prompt as well as "id" to confirm my username

Comment: I've forgot that the key comment has to be your GCE username. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly thanks Martin.I basically pasted the entire thing and noticed that Google already identified the username from the key. I then modified the name to something more convenient and am all set. Thanks a lot for your help!